How long does poison last?
It seems like poison lasts about 1/3 of Nathan's HP, and that new damage sources that would normally poison Nathan, don't refresh the time-to-cure counter?
Since if they did, I probably wouldn't have survived the Battle Arena's poison room, on ~23 HP from ~400/1110, and getting hit along the way.
But exactly how long does it take for a cure? Is it exactly 33 seconds, to deal approximately 1/3 damage, at 1% of Nathan's HP / s? Or am I worse at whip-only combat and it's only 25 seconds, given that I got hit like maybe 5 times and that shouldn't have been <100 damage?
